# Qt-> how to set ALT key active

Tags: c++, qt

Can someone please explain how to set the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key as active permanently?
I'm trying to make an application for Ubuntu and I need to make it active.
I want to add it to the code below in the `if` statement:

```
void MainWindow::on_checkBoxTitleBar_toggled(bool checked)
{
    settings->setValue("systemTitle", checked);
    ui->buttonMinimize->setVisible(!checked);
    ui->buttonClose->setVisible(!checked);


    if(!checked) {
        this->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint );
        //here i whant the new code line for the ALT key
    } else {
        this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint );
}
```

I'm new to C++, just don't really understand how C++ works, but I'm trying.

Comment: By alt key, do you mean that you want really easy shortcuts to your menus in just your program?  Like instead of `Alt+Q` to quit, you could use just `Q` or just `S` for save instead of `Alt+S`?

Comment: Yea thats right, so how do i do that pls?

Answer (score 0):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QShortcut.html#details

Basically, when you create a menu item in `QMainWindow` and you use an `&` in your naming, it will create an automatic shortcut for you.

You can make explicit shortcuts and tie them to an existing `QAction`.

<strike>I'll put up some example code shortly.</strike>

Update: Something like the following should do it for you.

```
foreach(QAction * action, this->menuBar()->findChildren<QAction*>())
{
    foreach(QKeySequence * keySequence, action->shortcuts())
    {
        QString shortcutString = keySequence->toString();
        qDebug() << action->text() << "has shortcut" << shortcutString;
        if(shortcutString.contains("Alt+"))
        {
            action->setShortcut(QKeySequencekeySequence(shortcutString.remove("Alt+"));
            // you may want to also try setShortcuts()
            // if you want to support both with and without the alt key pressed
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:  Solution according to comments, through example code.

Basically what happens is a global event notifier replaces all the keypresses with an Alt press beforehand, and modifies the keypress with an Alt Modifier.

application.h

```
#ifndef APPLICATION_H
#define APPLICATION_H

#include <QApplication>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QKeySequence>
#include <QShortcutEvent>
#include <QWindow>
#include <QShortcut>

class Application : public QApplication
{
public:
    explicit Application(int &argc, char** argv): QApplication(argc, argv)
    {
        m_checkBox = 0;
    }
    void setCheckBoxLink(QCheckBox * checkBox)
    {
        m_checkBox = checkBox;
    }
private:
    bool notify(QObject *receiver_, QEvent *e)
    {
        if(m_checkBox == 0 || !m_checkBox->isChecked())
            return QApplication::notify(receiver_, e);

        QKeyEvent * ke, *ke2;
        QShortcutEvent * se;
        switch (e->type())
        {
        case QEvent::KeyPress:
//            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << e->type();
            ke = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(e);
            if((ke->modifiers() & Qt::AltModifier) == 0)
            {
                qDebug() << "No Alt";
                ke2 = new QKeyEvent(ke->type(), 0, Qt::AltModifier);
                this->postEvent(receiver_, ke2);
                ke->setModifiers(Qt::AltModifier);
            }
            else
            {
                qDebug() << "Alt";
            }
            break;
        case QEvent::KeyRelease:
        default:
            break;
        }
        return QApplication::notify(receiver_, e);
    }

    QCheckBox * m_checkBox;
};

#endif // APPLICATION_H
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include "application.h"
#include <QMenuBar>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QAction>
#include <QShortcut>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QStatusBar>
#include <QDebug>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0) : QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        this->setCentralWidget(new QWidget());
        this->centralWidget()->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout());

        QCheckBox * checkBox = new QCheckBox("Alt Key");

        this->centralWidget()->layout()->addWidget(checkBox);

        ((Application*)qApp)->setCheckBoxLink(checkBox);

        QMenu * menu = new QMenu("E&xample");
        this->menuBar()->addMenu(menu);
        menu->addAction("Slot &1", this, SLOT(on_slot1()));
        menu->addAction("Slot &2", this, SLOT(on_slot2()));
        menu->addAction("Slot &3", this, SLOT(on_slot3()));
        menu->addAction("Slot &4", this, SLOT(on_slot4()));
        menu->addAction("Slot &5", this, SLOT(on_slot5()));
        menu->addAction("Slot &6", this, SLOT(on_slot6()));
        menu->addAction("Slot &A", this, SLOT(on_slotA()));
        menu->addAction("Slot &B", this, SLOT(on_slotB()));
        menu->addAction("Slot &C", this, SLOT(on_slotC()));
        menu->addAction("Slot &D", this, SLOT(on_slotD()));
        menu->addAction("Slot &E", this, SLOT(on_slotE()));
        menu->addAction("Slot &F", this, SLOT(on_slotF()));
    }

    ~MainWindow(){}

public slots:
    void on_slot1(){ qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO; this->statusBar()->showMessage(Q_FUNC_INFO); }
    void on_slot2(){ qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO; this->statusBar()->showMessage(Q_FUNC_INFO); }
    void on_slot3(){ qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO; this->statusBar()->showMessage(Q_FUNC_INFO); }
    void on_slot4(){ qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO; this->statusBar()->showMessage(Q_FUNC_INFO); }
    void on_slot5(){ qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO; this->statusBar()->showMessage(Q_FUNC_INFO); }
    void on_slot6(){ qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO; this->statusBar()->showMessage(Q_FUNC_INFO); }
    void on_slotA(){ qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO; this->statusBar()->showMessage(Q_FUNC_INFO); }
    void on_slotB(){ qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO; this->statusBar()->showMessage(Q_FUNC_INFO); }
    void on_slotC(){ qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO; this->statusBar()->showMessage(Q_FUNC_INFO); }
    void on_slotD(){ qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO; this->statusBar()->showMessage(Q_FUNC_INFO); }
    void on_slotE(){ qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO; this->statusBar()->showMessage(Q_FUNC_INFO); }
    void on_slotF(){ qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO; this->statusBar()->showMessage(Q_FUNC_INFO); }
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "application.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Application a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: no thats not what i want, i just want a shortcut for the mouse so i dont need to press the Alt key. and this must be active only if i have frameless window, please look at my code above.

Comment: See new solution.  Be warned, it may break typing anywhere in the program, like in textedits, lineedits, and other kinds of shortcuts like Ctrl+C, etc.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it by capturing and modifying the X11 keyboard events, but you really don't want to do that: it's non-portable, it's error prone and just plain ugly.

What you can do, however, is overload the keyPressEvent() function from QWidget. Say you want to capture the 'S' key in your MainWindow to active a save (QMainWindow is derived from QWidget, in case you're wondering). The following might work:

```
void MyMainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
  if (event->key() == Qt::Key_S)
  {
    save();
  }
  else
  {
    QMainWindow::keyPressEvent(event); // process other keys normally
  }
}
```

This captures both 's' and 'S'; add checks for Shift/Control as you see fit.

Note that this will grab *all* 's' keys in your main window; typing a name in an input box would be problematic. But dialogs should be safe since they are not derived from QMainWindow.

Comment: Well...this is not what im lokin' for...and u are right, but there are no input fields, no text righting will be used so the the alt key will be used just for mouse clicks left right